# Apply middleware to NestJs route method

Tags: module, routes, nestjs, middleware

I have my NestJs module set up as:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [MyController],
})
export class MyModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(MyMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('/myRoute');
  }
}
```

How do I apply MyMiddleware to only GET /myRoute but not POST /myRoute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#applying-middleware) something like this should do:

```js
@Module({
  controllers: [MyController],
})
export class MyModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(MyMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '/myRoute', method: RequestMethod.GET });
  }
}
```

Comment: Completely missed that in the docs! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I think that `@UseMiddleware()` is a missing feature because currently I don't see how to implement my logic.

I want to create a reusable `WithActionQueryParam('authenticate')` middleware/decorator and to integrate it into the `AuthController` by the following way:

```
@UseMiddleware(WithActionQueryParam('authenticate'))
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get()
async authenticate(@Req() req: Request) {
  return req.user;
}
    
@UseMiddleware(WithActionQueryParam('refreshToken'))
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get()
async refreshToken() {
  return this.authService.handleRefreshToken(req)
}
```

And what actually do the middleware is to check if `?action=targetValue` met the condition and if is not we call `next('route')`. I'm a bit disheartened by the initial enthusiasm of working with the Nest Js.

I want to be able to handle the requests by query param which is very easy to be implemented with Express but unfortunately not so easy with Nest JS.

I know that I can place a few if conditions into the first controller but I like way more the described way above.